# How is the ownership/copyright of AI-generated content determined?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I've been looking on the internet about current laws concerning the ownership and copyright of AI-generated content. And for most of them that I've seen, most of them do not consider the AI that created them the owner of the output. However, would the output of the AI be considered a joint production (the data and creation of the AI model and the generation of the output may have involved several parties) or is the individual pressing the button ordering the AI to generate the output the sole owner, or is the copyright of the output jointly shared by the people such as those who prepared the data, the people who built the model? It would be great if relevant laws or court cases could be provided too.

Comment: In general, yes, but I'd like to know how this is viewed by laws in Singapore or Asia. I've tried looking on the internet but haven't seen anything significant yet.

Comment: These answers quite answer my question, but still don't answer whether the party that created the AI model is eligible to claiming the copyright to content generated by its AI models.

Comment: @user1039203 they do: the first question says public domain, as in, **there is no copyright** and the second question says likewise. **nobody** owns copyright.

Answer (score 0):

### Only a human can own copyright

There is no copyright in non-human (inc. AI) generated content.